# IE8 absolute position + opacity problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Im having this problem only with IE8 it even works well on IE6!!...

Im appending 2 divs dynamically to the body and absolute positioning them so they get one above the other so it looks like one div... this works ok, untill i make then transparent with

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

I made the simplest demo to show the problem: http://anferth.com/tests/divs-problem/

In the demo first appear the two divs without opacity, they look like one, but 1sec after it sets the opacity to 0.5 and the divs get separated by 1px (**only in IE8**).

The code here: http://jsfiddle.net/messutiEdd/MNPrq/

Thanks in advance

Comment: One-pixel off errors in IE sometimes appear because you have the page zoomed (it's not very good at doing the zoom calculations.) Are you at the default page zoom factor? If not, this might explain why you're seeing the problem and other people aren't.

Comment: i cant believe it you are right!! my browser was at 95%, i was so sure it was a bug on IE8 -.- never thought on that... thanks now i can continue with my live

Comment: Well, it really is a bug in IE8, just not the one you were expecting :) I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an off-by-one-pixel bug in IE8 that other people can't reproduce, chances are good that you have the page zoomed to something other than the default level. IE doesn't seem to be great at scaling the page in some cases, and so zooming will sometimes cause problems with object positioning and image scaling.

Try resetting your zoom level and see if the problem disappears. I'd guess that (a) there's not a lot you can do about this, and (b) that people who habitually use zoom in IE8 are used to these little issues and probably won't shout about it...

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with your sample i have come up with this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append('<div class="af_sel af_right"></div>');
    $("body").append('<div class="af_sel af_bottom"></div>');

        var _top = (screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI) < 1 ? 291 : 290;

        $(".af_sel.af_right").css({
            'top': _top ,
            'left': 202,
            'width': 400,
            'height': 114
        });

        $(".af_sel.af_bottom").css({
            'top': 404,
            'left': 202,
            'width': 400,
            'height': 263
        });

        $(".af_sel").css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'display': 'none',
        'z-index': '1000'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".af_sel").show();

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".af_sel").css({
                'filter': ' alpha(opacity=50)'
            });
        }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
    });
    window.onresize = function()
    {

        var _top = (screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI) < 1 ? 291 : 290; // (screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI) = Zoom Level

        $(".af_sel.af_right").css({
            'top': _top ,
            'left': 202,
            'width': 400,
            'height': 114
        });
    }
```

There is still a pixel gap when zoomed to 125%, however this should set you on your way. 
to get the current zoom factor you will use (IE8) screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI
this will return zoom relative to 1. i.e 75% = 0.75, 100% = 1, 125% = 1.25, ect...

Best of luck!

Comment: Syntax errors... In JSON, the keys should not be in quotes, but the values should be.

Comment: Good call. I do not use JSON or JQuery, I wouldn't have caught that.

Comment: thank you but i haven't even realized my browser wasn't 100% of zoom... but this can be useful though :)